# How to Open downloaded file on notification click in android?

Tags: android, download, mime-types, android-notifications

I am downloaded a file from gmail. After download complete I need to be able to click on the notification to open downloaded file in my application.
my file type is csv.

[image]

click on the above downloaded file it opens through my app.how to open?

```
<activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".Fakeactivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="file" />
                <data android:host="*" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/comma-separated-values" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.csv" />
            </intent-filter> 
        </activity>
```

Using the above code to open csv file through my app.in FakeActivty i have write code reading the csv file.

Answer (score 0):

have you implement function of click on notification 
and your program can handle open csv files here is a code for read csv file
here is the code of opening activity which will response for show the csv file

```
   final Intent intent = new Intent(this, CSVClass.class);
      \\ data you want to send to CSV
    intent.putExtra("key", "value");
    final PendingIntent contentIntent = 
     PendingIntent.getActivity(this,  
      0, intent), 0);
  public class CSVFile {
  InputStream inputStream;

  public CSVFile(InputStream inputStream){
    this.inputStream = inputStream;
  }

   public List read(){
    List resultList = new ArrayList();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new 
    InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    try {
        String csvLine;
        while ((csvLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] row = csvLine.split(",");
            resultList.add(row);
        }
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error in reading CSV file: "+ex);
    }
    finally {
        try {
            inputStream.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error while closing input   
        stream: "+e);
        }
    }
    return resultList;
    }

 }
```

source http://javapapers.com/android/android-read-csv-file/

Comment: reading is done already in my activity. but after downloading click on my file it is not open.Actually i don't know where to write the function of notification onclick?

Comment: your problem is in click notification as I understand you need to add in the place you create notification in your code                                                 final Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
intent.setData(data);
intent.putExtra("key", "value");
final PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent), 0);

Comment: if you want your application to open file from download you need to set broadcast receiver to tell operating system that your program is able to open files of .csv

Comment: if you want your application to open file from download you need to modify  in intent filter    of your activity                                                                                         <data android:mimeType="*/*" />